# Widgets not loads after creating custom theme magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created custom theme. Sample data not loads on new created theme.
when I have checked

> Admin -> Widgets -> Design Package/Theme

Option to change Theme is disable. Is there another way to avoid creating new Widgets .
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've never really understood why this isn't editable post creation. The only option I'm aware of is to update the theme_id directly in the DB.

Running a query such as `UPDATE widget_instance SET theme_id = x WHERE theme_id = y` whereby x is the new theme id and y is the old theme id, should do the job.

Comment: Solution is good. But this doesn't work. I need to create it manually. Don't know why.

Comment: Having reflected on it for awhile, I imagine the reason it doesn't allow you to edit the theme, is potentially due to the layout handles, and the fact the chosen handle may not exist in the new theme. This would also explain why they DB query (which works, I used it after an M1 migration) wouldn't work, because the target layout handle doesn't exist.